# How do i extract a value from a list

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this:

```
0       [{'label': 1, 'prob': 0.5001602182558444}, {'l...
1       [{'label': 1, 'prob': 0.4983993145492764}, {'l...
2       [{'label': 1, 'prob': 0.5001580480134967}, {'l...
3       [{'label': 1, 'prob': 0.49975722925774013}, {'...
4       [{'label': 1, 'prob': 0.5028022960621467}, {'l...
                              ...                        
4475    [{'label': 1, 'prob': 0.5003302402940771}, {'l...
4476    [{'label': 1, 'prob': 0.49855059266658663}, {'...
4477    [{'label': 1, 'prob': 0.5031390463863391}, {'l...
4478    [{'label': 1, 'prob': 0.5038517971727202}, {'l...
4479    [{'label': 1, 'prob': 0.499373494895517}, {'la...
Name: Response_prob, Length: 4480, dtype: object
```

each entry looks something like this:

```
[{'label': 1, 'prob': 0.5001602182558444}, {'label': 0, 'prob': 0.49983978174415555}]
```

I want to extract the prob value from label:1

I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Is the list assigned to a variable?

Comment: Just to confirm: you have a list, with 4480 sublists, and each sublist contains two dicts?

Comment: What expected output? Do you use pandas package here?

Comment: That's a data frame, not a list

Answer (score 2):

You can try this if the "label 1" is always in the first dictionary:

```
[d.get('prob') for d in df['Response_prob'].str[0]]
```